# GitHub Action COPY failed: no source files were specified

Tags: docker, dockerfile, github-actions

Configuring the GitHub Action to build a image of this project I am getting this error:

```
Step 5/7 : COPY /target/*.jar app.jar
COPY failed: no source files were specified
```

This is the project Dockerfile, and I am referencing the file from build context path, not from relative path.

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine as build
COPY . /usr/app
WORKDIR /usr/app
RUN chmod +x mvnw \
    && ./mvnw --version \
    && ./mvnw clean package
COPY /usr/app/target/*.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","app.jar"]
```

I already verified if the file exist and read permissions with `ls -l /target` command:

```
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 Oct 18 15:35 classes
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 Oct 18 15:35 generated-sources
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 Oct 18 15:35 generated-test-sources
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root      48625321 Oct 18 15:35 learning-spring-boot-0.0.1.jar
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root         33089 Oct 18 15:35 learning-spring-boot-0.0.1.jar.original
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Oct 18 15:35 maven-archiver
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 Oct 18 15:35 maven-status
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Oct 18 15:35 surefire-reports
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 Oct 18 15:35 test-classes
```

And this is the output with `find .` after the `./mvnw clean package` command:

```
./target/learning-spring-boot-0.0.1.jar
./target/maven-archiver
./target/maven-archiver/pom.properties
./target/generated-sources
./target/generated-sources/annotations
./target/surefire-reports
```

Locally runs using the relative path, but fails with path from build context.

```
COPY /target/*.jar app.jar
```

[Here](https://github.com/josephrodriguez/learning-spring-boot) is the project url.

What I am missing?

Comment: Have you tried building this dockerfile locally, not on github?  Is the `app.jar` committed and in the git repo with the correct permissions? Try building locally on a fresh clone of the repo.

Comment: Yes, sorry, see my update. Let me check for repository permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looked to me like you wanted to use a multi-stage docker build, but you did not start the second stage. The second `COPY` step is not working because it is still in the same stage. And like BMitch mentioned, within the same stage, you can copy only from the build context using COPY. I made a couple of changes(started second stage, used `--from` in COPY) to your `Dockerfile` and it builds fine now. Dockerfile contents below:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine as build
COPY . /usr/app
WORKDIR /usr/app
RUN chmod +x mvnw \
    && ./mvnw --version \
    && ./mvnw clean package

FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
COPY --from=build /usr/app/target/*.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","app.jar"]
```

Comment: Awesome, I understand better now, by the way this multistage build reduce a lot my image size ~70 MB, excellent

Answer (score 0):

`ADD` includes content from your build context into the image, it does not copy files within your image. For the latter, just do a `RUN cp ...` command, e.g.

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine as build
COPY . /project
WORKDIR /project
RUN chmod +x mvnw \
 && ./mvnw --version \
 && ./mvnw clean package \
 && cp ./target/learning-spring-boot-0.0.1.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","app.jar"]
```

Since you changed `WORKDIR` to be `/project`, that shouldn't be included in the `cp` unless you use an absolute path.

Comment: I still receive the same kind of error: `cp: can't stat './project/target/learning-spring-boot-0.0.1.jar': No such file or directory`